# Geometry Question: Prove that the two angles are equal:

Tags: geometry

Edit: Now I know what I was originally calling a "string" is actually called a "chord", so I have edited the question to change that.

Sorry for my wording, I'm not sure what specific terms you guys use in English to describe what I'm about to describe, but I'll try my best to explain it. So the problem goes like this: Two chords that are not diameters and are of the same length intersect at a diameter. Prove that the angle formed by the first chord with the diameter is the same as the angle formed by the second chord and the diameter. Here's a rough drawing:

[image: rough drawing]

Here point o is the center of the circle, line segment ab is the first chord and line segment cd is the second chord, they are both the same length, and they all intersect with a diameter at point p. We have to prove that angle apf is equal to angle dpf.

So far I'm stuck, all I've been able to come up with is that arc ab must be equal to arc cd because of the segment being the same length, thus angle afb must be equal to angle cfd, but I haven't been able to get far with that alone. How would you solve this problem? I'd appreciate an easy o understand explanation since I'm not very good at geometry.

Comment: The English word for what you are calling "string" is "chord"

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your diagram with a few modifications. Treating your points as being their equivalent upper case versions (since that's more standard), then I have labeled the midpoint of $AB$ as $G$, the midpoint of $CD$ as $H$, and added the line segments of $OG$ and $OH$.

[image: Diagram of OP with a couple of points and line segments added]

Since $\lvert OA\rvert = \lvert OB\rvert$, and similarly $\lvert OC\rvert = \lvert OD\rvert$, as they are circle radii, then $\triangle OAB$ and $\triangle OCD$ are both isosceles. Thus, as indicated in [Isosceles triangle height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle#Height), the altitude and median coincide. This is due to, for example, using SSS that $\triangle DHO \cong CHO$ so $\measuredangle DHO = \measuredangle CHO$ and, as they form a straight line, the angles add to $180^{\circ}$ so each is $90^{\circ}$. This results in, as shown,

$$\measuredangle OGA = \measuredangle OHD = 90^\circ$$

Since $\lvert AG\rvert = \lvert DH\rvert$, as they are both half of the equal lengths of $\lvert AB\rvert$ and $\lvert CD\rvert$, then using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) with $\triangle OGA$ and $\triangle OHD$, we get that with the hypotenuse and a side length of $2$ right-angled triangles being equal, then so is the third side length (with it being the square root of the difference of squares of the hypotenuse and side lengths), i.e.,

$$\lvert OG\rvert = \lvert OH\rvert$$

Once again using the Pythagorean theorem with $\triangle OGP$ and $\triangle OHP$, we get that

$$\lvert GP\rvert = \lvert HP\rvert$$

By SSS, we now have $\triangle GPO \cong \triangle HPO$, so this finally gives that

$$\measuredangle GPO = \measuredangle HPO \;\;\to\;\; \measuredangle APF = \measuredangle DPF$$

Comment: Thanks! I understand it, except for one thing. How does knowing that the triangles are isosceles show that the angles must be 90 degrees? I can see how knowing the triangles are isosceles shows that the lines OG and OH bisect the angles AOB and COD, but I don't know how to conclude those lines are perpendicular to the chords.

Comment: @zlaaemi You're welcome. Regarding the triangles being isosceles meaning that the median is also an altitude, I updated my answer to include a link to the Wikipedia article about that, as well as an explanation about it being both of the smaller triangles being congruent, so the two angles at the median are equal and, since they sum to $180^{\circ}$, they each must be $90^{\circ}$.